# Using more than one resolve in states.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a route as below:

```
var entryShow = {
  name: 'entry.show',
  url: '/:entry_id',
  views: {
    '@':{
      templateUrl: TEMPLATES.entry_show,
      controller : 'EntryShowController',
      resolve: {
        entryData: ['$stateParams', 'Entry', function($stateParams, Entry){
          return Entry.getEntry($stateParams.entry_id);
        }],
        entryHistory: ['$stateParams','Entry',function($stateParams,Entry){
          return Entry.getHistory($stateParams.entry_id);
        }]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In my controller I have added the two resolves as follows :

```
App.controller('EntryShowController',['$scope','$state','entryData', 'Entry',
function($scope, $state, entryData, entryHistory, Entry) {
    ...
    $scope.entry = entryData.data.entry;
    console.log('Entry History');
    console.log(entryData);
    console.log(entryHistory);
    $scope.entry.history = entryHistory.data;
    ...
}]);
```

Here in console.log I get the correct result for entryData but for entryHistory I get the entryService object instead of the result. Also when I swapped the getEntry and getHistoyr making getHistory being called in first resolve then the value in entryHistory was correct but in entryData I got the entryService object.
I have also checked the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-resolve) for using resolves in state.js. What am I doing wrong ?

Following is my entryService:

```
App.factory('Entry', ['$http','Common', function($http,Common){
var entryService = {};

entryService.getEntry = function(entry_id) {
    show_page_loader();
    return $http.get(URLS.entry_show_path, {params: { id: entry_id }})
      .success(function(result){
        return result;
      })
      .error(function(data){
        common_flash_error_message();
      });
    };

...

entryService.getHistory = function(entry_id){
    return $http.get(
      URLS.entry_history_path,
      {
        params: {id: entry_id}
      }
    )
      .success(function(data){
        return data;
      })
      .error(function(data){
        common_flash_error_message();
      });
};

return entryService;
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgot to inject `entryHistory` into the array so you've mixup your injections:

```
App.controller('EntryShowController',[
         '$scope', '$state', 'entryData', 'Entry',
function( $scope,   $state,   entryData,   entryHistory, Entry) {

}]);
```

Here, `enterHistory` will hold `entry`,